# JavaScript Is not working. Showing Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, css

The following contains my HTML code
[image]

And here Is the JS code....

```js
const navbtn = document.querySelector('.navbar__btn');
const navlink = document.querySelector('.navbar__link');

navbtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let value = navlink.classList.contains('navbar__collapse');


    if (value) {
        navlink.classList.remove('navbar__collapse');
    } else {
        navlink.classList.add('navbar__collapse');
    }
});
```

and here is the CSS code.

```css
.navbar_link{
    list-style-type: none;
    transition: all 2s ease;
    /* */
    height:0;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar__collapse{
    height: 250px;
}
```

But when I run it on my server It shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null" at line 6 of my js code. PLease any help will be appritiatable.

Comment: Could you do us a favor and add the html as code instead of an image?

Comment: It is `navbar_link` and not `navbar__link` with 2 `_`. This is what the SS is showing

Comment: Please include actual html not pictures of it. We can't run your code against a picture

Comment: @Castro Roy. I am really Ashamed. I should have found that tiny thing. I have been spending the last 2 hours.  Now my code is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it was the double underbar `_` that was throwing things off.

Here's a working sample of your code.

```js
const navbtn = document.querySelector('.navbar_btn');
const navlink = document.querySelector('.navbar_link');

navbtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let value = navlink.classList.contains('navbar_collapse');

  if (value) {
    navlink.classList.remove('navbar_collapse');
  } else {
    navlink.classList.add('navbar_collapse');
  }
});
```

```css
.navbar_btn {
  margin: 10px;
}

.navbar_link {
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.navbar_collapse {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<button class="navbar_btn">Button</button>
<div class="navbar_link"></div>
```